# How to derive the volume of the region left when a plane cuts a solid elliptical cylinder?

Tags: integration, conic-sections, volume, elliptic-integrals

I need to be able to calculate the volume of an elliptical cylinder that is cut by a plane. It is similar to slicing a cylinder and finding the volume, only this time with an elliptical cylinder. I was wondering if there is a suitable derivation to get a formula for the Volume. Thank you for any help!

Comment: With only one plane you have an infinite volume. I assume that you already have one as a base. Why don't you just do an integral? Find out the intersection first.

Comment: The volume is $hA$ where $h$ is the height at the central axis of the cylinder and $A$ is  area of the base. This formula actually works for any cylinder whose base is centrally symmetric with respect to its center. For a proof, make two copies of your cylinder, flip one of them upside down, twist it along the axis for $180^\circ$ and then glue the two cylinders along their cross section. You get a ordinary cylinder with twice the height and volume!

Comment: @Andrei yes there is a base at the origin I forgot to mention that. I am currently trying my luck with triple integrals. Thank you.

Comment: Let the cylinder base be $(x/a) ^2+(y/b)^2=1$ and the region bounded by ellipse be denoted by $D$. The volume of a right cylinder  with base $D$ between the planes $z=0$ and $z=ax+by+c$ is $\iiint_{D} (ax+by+c) \, dx\, dy$.